# getting the error - Error CS1061 “...Does Not Contain Definition and No Extension Method...accepting a first argument of type ” could be found

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ado.net

I am new to.NET Visual Studio and building an ASP.NET MVC Application.

This is my code and I am getting error on the Add Part

```
namespace proj.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Employee
        emp_RegEntities dbObj = new emp_RegEntities();

        public ActionResult Employee()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddEmployee(Detail model)
        {
            Detail obj = new Detail();
            obj.EmpName = model.EmpName;
            obj.Contact = model.Contact;
            obj.City = model.City;
            obj.State = model.State;
            obj.Field = model.Field;

            dbObj.Detail.Add(obj);
            dbObj.SaveChanges();

            return View("Employee");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It is quite unlikely you will get a proper answer without a proper question. 
Paste the error you have received.

Answer (score 0):

A sugguestion and hope this gets solve your problem.

1. Initialize the object inside the *constructor*
2. *Dipose* the object when class dispose

**More Refined Code**

```
namespace proj.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        private emp_RegEntities dbObj;

        // Initialize dbObj inside Constructor
        public EmployeeController()
        {
            dbObj = new emp_RegEntities();
        }

        //Dispose of dbObj when EmployeeController class dispose
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            dbObj.Dispose();
        }

        public ActionResult Employee()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddEmployee(Detail model)
        {
            Detail obj = new Detail();
            obj.EmpName = model.EmpName;
            obj.Contact = model.Contact;
            obj.City = model.City;
            obj.State = model.State;
            obj.Field = model.Field;

            dbObj.Detail.Add(obj);
            dbObj.SaveChanges();

            return View("Employee");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you don't pass the model object to view in the post

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddEmployee(Detail model)
{
    Detail obj = new Detail();
    obj.EmpName = model.EmpName;
    obj.Contact = model.Contact;
    obj.City = model.City;
    obj.State = model.State;
    obj.Field = model.Field;

    dbObj.Detail.Add(obj);
    dbObj.SaveChanges();

    return View(obj); //I guess u wanna return the model            
}
```